# Spring boot application: how to hotfix js changes

Tags: spring-boot

I am working on Spring Boot application. Every time when I do JavaScript change I had to restart tomcat server. Can someone know how to hotfix JavaScript changes in while running the Spring Boot project from Eclipse?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume you are running on an older version of Spring Boot, older than 1.3.0 (if I'm not wrong.)
Sprint Boot never had the feature to auto-start the web server, live reload and the like.

You need to add the following dependency to your `pom.xml`

```
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-devtools</artifactId>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

**EDIT-1:**
If you are using IntelliJ IDE then you can follow these steps to resolve your issue.

I had the same problem but I already fixed it. You can follow this steps:

- Go to Help-> Find Action and type "Registry".
- Check this option `compiler.automake.allow.when.app.running` & save
- Go to "Settings->Build, Execution, Deployment->Compiler" and mark "Build project automatically".
- Click on "Apply changes".

If these steps go well, then you should be displayed a warning on your Spring Boot configuration about **backgroud compilation** which will load your static file changes as well with a browser refresh.

**EDIT-2:**

- If you are using eclipse, then you can integrate with a plugin called jRebel
- Also consider making this selection by default (*Project* -> *Build Automatically*)

Hope this helps!

Comment: Hi After adding this tag only java changes gets auto-deployed not the js and html changes.

Comment: @Harshal, check my edited answer - if solves your problem?

Comment: I am using eclipse IDE. Any idea what setting have to do in eclipse

Answer (score 1):

You have to add the [Developer Tools](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/using-boot-devtools.html) from Spring in your `pom.xml`

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-devtools</artifactId>
</dependency>
```

Answer (score 0):

I have also added maven resource plugin. After this any html changes gets deployed immediately. Also keep default option enabled for project build.
Project -> Build Automatically

```
<plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-resources-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.6</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>copy-resources</id>
                        <phase>validate</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>copy-resources</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <outputDirectory>${basedir}/target/classes/static</outputDirectory>
                            <resources>
                                <resource>
                                    <directory>src/main/resources/</directory>
                                    <filtering>true</filtering>
                                </resource>
                            </resources>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
```